# CSS border-right doesn't show up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to show a d3 bar chart in a tr with border of 1px. It works fine in Firefox but in chrome, the right border isn't showing up! maybe it's a space problem or I am missing something. Anyway, this is the code for tr (table is 1000px width):

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
<tr style="border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;">
     <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow" style="padding: 0 !important;">
        <div class="accordian-body collapse" style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;" align="center" id="graphDiv1">
        </div>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the d3 javascript function:

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 150, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: Using that HTML, the right border displays fine for me in Chrome. Would you mind posting more CSS that applies to this table?

Comment: Also, the JavaScript that you've posted isn't very helpful... All you're showing is variable declarations; nothing is actually *happening*.

Comment: … so better show an online example where we can _see_ the effect.

Comment: @Interdasting Actually, something _is_ happening. Variables are being declared.

Answer (score 0):

Change following.

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
```

to...

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding-top: 10px;">
```

You are setting the width of the table to 100% where your javascript should already be defining the width.